# How to get the id of the local file

Tags: c#, database, algorithm, sqlite

I have a database table, which saves the file/folder structure  with the following definition:

```
id    parentid     fileOrFolderName
111    222          aaa.txt
222    333          folderA
333    Root         folderB
444    222          bbb.doc
```

...........

The "Root" is a special Id for a predefined root folder.  so, the above records mean: There is a file located in  "Rootfolder\folderB\folderA\aaa.txt", and its id is "111".

Now, given the full path of the file, I'd like to get its id. For example:

GetFileId("RootFolder\folderB\folderA\aaa.txt")   will return "111".

There are about 10 - 50 thousands records in this table, how can I code GetFileId function right and efficient?

This question is not limited to any language or database, what I need is the right algorithm.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The GetFileId function is written by C#(or Java, or any other language), and sql statements are called inside of this function. Please advice, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this data structure, the obvious algorithm (do one separate lookup per level) is the only one that works.

For each level in the directory hierarchy, do:

```sql
SELECT id FROM MyTable WHERE parentid = ? AND fileOrFolderName = ?
```

You could combine all lookups into one nested statement:

```sql
SELECT id FROM MyTable
WHERE parentid =
   (SELECT id FROM MyTable
    WHERE parentid =
       (SELECT id FROM MyTable
        WHERE parentid = 'Root'
          AND fileOrFolderName = 'folderB')
      AND fileOrFolderName = 'folderA')
  AND fileOrFolderName = 'aaa.txt'
```

However, this would not be much faster, but would make query construction more complex.

---

To make it fast, use proper indexes.
(An index on the two columns `parentid` and `fileOrFolderName` should help. A [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx) on these two and the `id` column might be a little better.)

Comment: Thanks CL, not very clear about "separate lookup per level",  can you give some pseudo code ?